# multithread - pthread - mutex, is it working?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, c++14, mutex

i am using threads to run 2 function that 
print, "-----" and "########".

Im was trying to use a mutex, that for what i understond it should block any incoming threads, but when i use lock mutex it doesnt block any incoming threads, has you can see on the resul(down there).
Im i miss understanding what mutex does or is the mutex that's not runnig properly.

love to hear your opinions... Thanks :D

Im using GNU gcc compiler - donloaded from the Mingw website

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* print (void* e){
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(1){
        cout << "########" <<endl;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
void* print1 (void* e){

    while(1){
        cout << "-----" <<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    pthread_t* threads;
    threads = new pthread_t;
//------------------------------------
    pthread_t* threads1;
    threads1 = new pthread_t;
 //-------------------------------------
    pthread_create(threads,NULL,print,(void*)NULL);
    pthread_create(threads1,NULL,print1,(void*)NULL);
    getchar();
    return false;
}
```

//--------------------     RESULT:

```
   "########" 
   "-----" 
   "########" 
   "-----" 
   "########"
   "-----"  
   "########"
   .....
   .....
```

With pthread_mutex_lock i was expcting something like:

```
  "########" 
   "########" 
   "########" 
   "########"
   "########"
   "########" 
   infinit .....
```

Comment: The print1 function does not appear to contain any code that pertains to your mutex.

Comment: slacker for what i understand by not puting lock mutex on print1, makes that print can call its routine first.

Comment: If your mutex is only ever locked by one thread, then it won't have any effect on the behavior of any other threads and therefore won't do anything useful.  The only time a thread gets blocked by a mutex is when the thread calls pthread_mutex_lock().

Comment: Got it .. thanks :D